# Adding custom labels to a Highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, coffeescript

I'm working on an interactive graph project using [Highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) and need a way to do the following:

*note: the screenshots I attached are of photoshop mocks, the points circled in red are what I'm interested in adding to my Highcharts graph.*

1. Custom 'point of interest' **axis markers**:
   [image: custom axis markers - highcharts]
2. Labels above a plotted series (the two above the dotted lines):

In this screenshot it's the **"Average Portfolio of..."** and **"Average Mutual..."** that I need to add to my graph.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, you can add text at any place you want to using [`Renderer.text()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text). Useful will be [`toPixels`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels) method - where you know 'point of interest' value, and need to get it's position on the plotting area. There is also plugin for [Current price indicator](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/28/Current%20Price%20Indicator).

Comment: This feels like a "give me the code" question. Please refer to this discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1007263